# JLex - How to identify comments that starts with "{" and ends with "}"

Tags: regex

Content of JLex file:

---

```
//Main
%%
//Possible text of file: {This is a comment}
Comments=[\{][.*][\}]
Whitespaces=[\ \r\n]

%% 
{Comments}{System.out.println("Line"+(yyline+1)+" Comments\t"+yytext());}
{Whitespaces}{}
```

---

Issue:

- It recognizes only `{` and `}` as a Comment

Expectation:

- The content inside of `{` and `}` should be recognized as Comment (as well as `{`,`}`)

Is there something wrong with this regular expression?

> regex:`[\{][.*][\}]`

---

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: What do you think the `[]` do? Looks like you confuse them with `()`. Also, please state the regex flavor you are using.

Comment: `[\{][.*][\}]` = `\{.*\}` !